# R sampling from a vector where adjacent elements are not allowed

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, montecarlo

Suppose I am allowed to distribute 100% of the weight along an 5-length vector. However, I can't put weights into two adjacent values and no value can be more than 50%.

For example,

```
[0, .5, 0, 0, .5] is good
[.5, .5, 0, 0,0] is not good
[.2, 0, .2, 0, .6] is good
[.2, 0, .2, .2, .2] is not good
```

I'd like to generate say 10,000 such vectors from which to run a monte carlo simulation.

I'm thinking I can do this with `expand.grid` but I'm not quite sure how.

I can generate a random one and then:

```
nonzero_weights = which(starting_weights>0)
grid_positions = expand.grid(startingPos = nonzero_weights, endingPos = nonzero_weights)
```

And then do some filtering and dropping but that seems messy. Why generate if I don't need them. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: If you control what adjacent values can be, then doesn't this mean that the values would not be truly random?  Why do you have the adjacency requirement?

Comment: @Tim, correct. For instance if that vector represents overlapping months, (Jan-Feb) vs (Feb-March) .... I wouldn't want any overlap.

Comment: In this particular problem there aren't many possibilities for the non-zero weights: (1,3,5), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5), (3,5). So you can select one of those 7 randomly. If it is not the first one, then the 2 weights must be 50%. Only the first scenario (1,3,5) needs filtering and dropping.

Comment: @papgeo -- how would this generalize to an 11-length vector? That's what I'm actually dealing with. I'm wondering if I can write out a recursive function to find all these positions.

Comment: @JosephWood: Yep, that's what I needed. Thanks! Nice package btw :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we did not have the adjacency restriction, this problem would not be that difficult with the tools currenty available in `R` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736928/4408538) more info). With the adjacency restriction, we have to do a little more work to get our desired result.

We first note that since we cannot have 2 consecutive numbers in a row of a vector with *n* columns (the OP clarified in the comments that they need *n = 11* so we will use this as our test case), that the maximum number of columns with a value is equal to `11 - floor(11 / 2) = 6`. This occurs when the values are present in the columns `1 3 5 7 9 11`. We should also note that since the maximum value is capped at 0.5 and we need the row to sum to 1, that the minimum number of columns with a value is equal to 2 since `ceiling(1 / 0.5) = 2`. With this information, we can begin our attack.

We first generate every combination of 11 choose 2 through 6. We then sift out combinations that violate the adjacency restriction. The latter part can easily be achieved by taking the `diff` of every row and checking if any of the resulting differences is equal to 1. Observe (N.B. we use `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) for all computations):

```
library(RcppAlgos)

vecLen <- 11L
lowComb <- as.integer(ceiling(1 / 0.5))
highComb <- 6L
numCombs <- length(lowComb:highComb)

allCombs <- lapply(lowComb:highComb, function(x) {
    comboGeneral(vecLen, x)
})

validCombs <- lapply(allCombs, function(x) {
    which(apply(x, 1, function(y) {
        !any(diff(y) == 1L)
    }))
})

combLen <- lengths(validCombs)
combLen
[1] 45 84 70 21  1

## subset each matrix of combinations using the
## vector of validCombs obtained above
myCombs <- lapply(seq_along(allCombs), function(x) {
    allCombs[[x]][validCombs[[x]], ]
})
```

We now need to find all combinations of `seq(0.05, 0.5, 0.05)` that sum to 1 for every possible length calculated above. Using the restraint features of `comboGeneral`, this is an easy task:

```
combSumOne <- lapply(lowComb:highComb, function(x) {
    comboGeneral(seq(5L,50L,5L), x, TRUE, 
                 constraintFun = "sum", 
                 comparisonFun = "==", 
                 limitConstraints = 100L) / 100
})

groupLen <- sapply(combSumOne, nrow)
groupLen
1 13 41 66 78
```

Now, we create a matrix with our desired number of columns and fill it will all possible combinations, using `myCombs` above to ensure the adjancency requirement is met.

```
myCombMat <- matrix(0L, nrow = sum(groupLen * combLen), ncol = vecLen)
s <- g <- 1L
e <- combRow <- nrow(combSumOne[[1L]])

for (a in myCombs[-numCombs]) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
        myCombMat[s:e, a[i, ]] <- combSumOne[[g]]
        s <- e + 1L
        e <- e + combRow
    }
    e <- e - combRow
    g <- g + 1L
    combRow <- nrow(combSumOne[[g]])
    e <- e + combRow
}

## the last element in myCombs is simply a
## vector, thus nrow would return NULL
myCombMat[s:e, myCombs[[numCombs]]] <- combSumOne[[g]]
```

Here is a glimpse of the output:

```
head(myCombMat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]  0.5    0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[2,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[3,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[4,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[5,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0    0     0     0
[6,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5    0     0     0

tail(myCombMat)
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[5466,] 0.10    0 0.10    0 0.20    0 0.20    0 0.20     0  0.20
[5467,] 0.10    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15     0  0.30
[5468,] 0.10    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.20     0  0.25
[5469,] 0.10    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.20    0 0.20     0  0.20
[5470,] 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15     0  0.25
[5471,] 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.20     0  0.20

set.seed(42)
mySamp <- sample(nrow(myCombMat), 10)
sampMat <- myCombMat[mySamp, ]
rownames(sampMat) <- mySamp

sampMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
5005 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.35 0.00   0.4  0.00
5126 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.20 0.00 0.20 0.00   0.0  0.30
1565 0.10 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00   0.5  0.00
4541 0.05 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.25   0.0  0.50
3509 0.00 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.25 0.00 0.00   0.0  0.35
2838 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.35 0.00 0.00   0.0  0.40
4026 0.05 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.20 0.00 0.50   0.0  0.00
736  0.00 0.00 0.10 0.00 0.40 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00   0.0  0.50
3590 0.00 0.00 0.15 0.00 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.30 0.00   0.0  0.35
3852 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.20 0.00 0.30 0.00   0.0  0.45

all(rowSums(myCombMat) == 1)
[1] TRUE
```

As you can see, every row sums to 1 and has no adjacent values.

If you really want permutations, we can generate all permutations of `seq(0.05, 0.5, 0.05)` that sum to 1 for every possible length (just like we did for the combination):

```
permSumOne <- lapply(lowComb:highComb, function(x) {
    permuteGeneral(seq(5L,50L,5L), x, TRUE, 
                   constraintFun = "sum", 
                   comparisonFun = "==", 
                   limitConstraints = 100L) / 100
})

groupLenPerm <- sapply(permSumOne, nrow)
groupLenPerm
[1]     1    63   633  3246 10872
```

And use these to create our matrix of all possible permutations that sum to 1 and meet our adjacency requirement:

```
myPermMat <- matrix(0L, nrow = sum(groupLenPerm * combLen), ncol = vecLen)
s <- g <- 1L
e <- permRow <- nrow(permSumOne[[1L]])

for (a in myCombs[-numCombs]) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
        myPermMat[s:e, a[i, ]] <- permSumOne[[g]]
        s <- e + 1L
        e <- e + permRow
    }
    e <- e - permRow
    g <- g + 1L
    permRow <- nrow(permSumOne[[g]])
    e <- e + permRow
}

## the last element in myCombs is simply a
## vector, thus nrow would return NULL
myPermMat[s:e, myCombs[[numCombs]]] <- permSumOne[[g]]
```

And, once again, here is glimpse of the output:

```
head(myPermMat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]  0.5    0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[2,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[3,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[4,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0    0     0     0
[5,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0    0     0     0
[6,]  0.5    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5    0     0     0

tail(myPermMat)
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[128680,] 0.15    0 0.20    0 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.15     0  0.15
[128681,] 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15     0  0.20
[128682,] 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.20     0  0.15
[128683,] 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.20    0 0.15     0  0.15
[128684,] 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.15     0  0.15
[128685,] 0.20    0 0.20    0 0.15    0 0.15    0 0.15     0  0.15

all(rowSums(myPermMat) == 1)
[1] TRUE
```

And, as the OP states, if we want to randomly pick 10000 of these we can use `sample` to achieve this:

```
set.seed(101)
mySamp10000 <- sample(nrow(myPermMat), 10000)
myMat10000 <- myPermMat[mySamp10000, ]
rownames(myMat10000) <- mySamp10000

head(myMat10000)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
47897 0.00  0.0 0.00 0.50  0.0 0.25  0.0 0.00 0.05   0.0  0.20
5640  0.25  0.0 0.15 0.00  0.1 0.00  0.5 0.00 0.00   0.0  0.00
91325 0.10  0.0 0.00 0.15  0.0 0.40  0.0 0.00 0.20   0.0  0.15
84633 0.15  0.0 0.00 0.35  0.0 0.30  0.0 0.10 0.00   0.1  0.00
32152 0.00  0.4 0.00 0.05  0.0 0.00  0.0 0.25 0.00   0.3  0.00
38612 0.00  0.4 0.00 0.00  0.0 0.35  0.0 0.10 0.00   0.0  0.15
```

As `RcppAlgos` is highly efficient, all steps above return instantly. On my 2008 Windows machine i5 2.5 GHz, the entire generation (including the permutations) takes less than 0.04 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can generate the binary samples by removing sampled indices from prev samples. Then generate the weights to be assigned to these binary samples:

```
idx <- 1:11

system.time(
    binsampl <- t(replicate(10000L, {
        x <- rep(0L, length(idx))
        while(length(idx) > 0L) {
            chosen <- if (length(idx) > 1L) sample(idx, 1L) else idx
            idx <- setdiff(idx, chosen + -1L:1L)
            x[chosen] <- 1L
        }
        x
    }))
)

system.time(
    weights <- t(apply(binsampl, 1, function(s) {
        y <- runif(sum(s))
        s[s==1L] <- y/sum(y) 
        s
    }))
)
head(weights)
```

output:

```
            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]
[1,] 0.114636912 0.00000000 0.1136963 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.1938791 0.00000000 0.3495739 0.00000000
[2,] 0.267907091 0.00000000 0.1487623 0.0000000 0.21628596 0.0000000 0.08326985 0.0000000 0.03803797
[3,] 0.000000000 0.06195168 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.07972502 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.3749550 0.00000000
[4,] 0.083384611 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.3867607 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.16300188 0.0000000 0.00000000
[5,] 0.005233208 0.00000000 0.4106275 0.0000000 0.15796746 0.0000000 0.10168549 0.0000000 0.00000000
[6,] 0.188153707 0.00000000 0.1867017 0.0000000 0.29426748 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.2962538 0.00000000
         [,10]     [,11]
[1,] 0.2282138 0.0000000
[2,] 0.0000000 0.2457368
[3,] 0.0000000 0.4833683
[4,] 0.3668528 0.0000000
[5,] 0.3244863 0.0000000
[6,] 0.0000000 0.0346233
```

Takes less than 1s to generate for 10k samples on my machine using R-3.5.1 Windows x64 8GB RAM 2.8GHz processor.