# R distribute weights over a vector

Tags: r, combinations

Suppose I have a vector in R

```
 0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     1     0
```

There can be no more than 6 "1"s anywhere in the vector. All other elements are 0.

I'm trying to get all possible values where I distribute "1" across the **1** positions where each value has to be <= 0.5.

So for instance:

```
0    .2    0    0    .3    0    0    0    0     .5     0 . <- OK

0    .35    0    0    .4    0    0    0    0     .25     0 <- OK
```

However

```
0    .2   0    0    .2    0    0    0    0     .6     0  <- not ok
```

The increments can go up by 0.05.

Thus in a vector with 3 "1"'s there are at most 20^3 combinations many of which will be bad as they will sum to greater than 1 or have values >0.5. Is there a faster way than to brute force this?

**Edit:**
I realized that I can come up with all possible weights quickly using:

```
temp <- expand.grid(replicate(sum(x),seq(0.05,.5,0.05), simplify=FALSE))
```

where x is my vector.

So now for each one of those in temp I want to put in positions where the 1's are in

```
 0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     1     0
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617501/) would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: As @www points out in the comments, you will miss some combinations/permutations if you rely on floating point arithmetic. To remedy this, we need to work with integer precision (i.e. instead of `seq(0, 0.5, 0.05)` we need `seq(0L, 50L, 5L)`) and divide our results by 100.

I authored the package `RcppAlgos` that is meant precisely for problems such as these:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
myCombs <- comboGeneral(seq(0L,50L,5L), 6, TRUE, 
                        constraintFun = "sum", 
                        comparisonFun = "==", 
                        limitConstraints = 100L) / 100
head(myCombs, n = 10)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    0    0    0 0.00 0.50 0.50
 [2,]    0    0    0 0.05 0.45 0.50
 [3,]    0    0    0 0.10 0.40 0.50
 [4,]    0    0    0 0.10 0.45 0.45
 [5,]    0    0    0 0.15 0.35 0.50
 [6,]    0    0    0 0.15 0.40 0.45
 [7,]    0    0    0 0.20 0.30 0.50
 [8,]    0    0    0 0.20 0.35 0.45
 [9,]    0    0    0 0.20 0.40 0.40
[10,]    0    0    0 0.25 0.25 0.50

tail(myCombs, n = 10)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[190,] 0.10 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.35
[191,] 0.10 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.30
[192,] 0.10 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.25 0.25
[193,] 0.10 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.20 0.25
[194,] 0.10 0.10 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20
[195,] 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.30
[196,] 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.25
[197,] 0.10 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.20 0.20
[198,] 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.25
[199,] 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.20
```

If you are interested in permutations, no problem:

```
myPerms <- permuteGeneral(seq(0L,50L,5L), 6, TRUE, 
                          constraintFun = "sum", 
                          comparisonFun = "==", 
                          limitConstraints = 100L) / 100

head(myPerms, n = 10)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5
 [2,]    0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5
 [3,]    0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0
 [4,]    0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.5
 [5,]    0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0
 [6,]    0  0.0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0
 [7,]    0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5
 [8,]    0  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
 [9,]    0  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
[10,]    0  0.5  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0

tail(myPerms, n = 10)
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[41109,] 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.20 0.15 0.15
[41110,] 0.15 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.20
[41111,] 0.15 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.15
[41112,] 0.15 0.20 0.15 0.20 0.15 0.15
[41113,] 0.15 0.20 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15
[41114,] 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.20
[41115,] 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.15
[41116,] 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.20 0.15 0.15
[41117,] 0.20 0.15 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15
[41118,] 0.20 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
```

Result is immediate:

```
system.time(permuteGeneral(seq(0L,50L,5L), 6, TRUE, 
                           constraintFun = "sum", 
                           comparisonFun = "==", 
                           limitConstraints = 100L) / 100)
 user  system elapsed 
0.005   0.001   0.006
```

**Quick Thoughts**

One may be tempted to attack this problem as an additive integer partition problem. There is a mapping from `seq(0, 0.5, 0.05)` to `0:11` as well as a mapping from `seq(0, 1, 0.05)` to `0:20`. The latter may not be obvious as to why it is helpful but indeed it is. There is a very nice package called `partitions` that comes equipped with a function for generating restricted partitions (that is, partitions of a given length).

```
library(partitions)
myParts <- t(as.matrix(restrictedparts(20, 6))) / 20

head(myParts)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 1.00 0.00    0    0    0    0
[2,] 0.95 0.05    0    0    0    0
[3,] 0.90 0.10    0    0    0    0
[4,] 0.85 0.15    0    0    0    0
[5,] 0.80 0.20    0    0    0    0
[6,] 0.75 0.25    0    0    0    0
```

As you can see, we have already violated are requirement of having numbers greater than 0.5. So we have to do a little extra work to get our final result:

```
myMax <- apply(myParts, 1, max)
myFinalParts <- myParts[-which(myMax > 0.5), ]

head(myFinalParts)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 0.50 0.50 0.00    0    0    0
[2,] 0.50 0.45 0.05    0    0    0
[3,] 0.50 0.40 0.10    0    0    0
[4,] 0.45 0.45 0.10    0    0    0
[5,] 0.50 0.35 0.15    0    0    0
[6,] 0.45 0.40 0.15    0    0    0

tail(myFinalParts, n = 10)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[190,] 0.35 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.10 0.10
[191,] 0.30 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.10 0.10
[192,] 0.25 0.25 0.15 0.15 0.10 0.10
[193,] 0.25 0.20 0.20 0.15 0.10 0.10
[194,] 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.10 0.10
[195,] 0.30 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.10
[196,] 0.25 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.10
[197,] 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.10
[198,] 0.25 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
[199,] 0.20 0.20 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
```

As you can see, we have the exact same solution above (see `myCombs`) only the columns are in a different order.

```
all.equal(myCombs, myFinalParts[,6:1])
[1] TRUE
```

For the permutation part, these are actually referred to as restricted integer [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).  We can call `partitions::compositions` and proceed similarly to the above where we will need to weed out those rows that break our rule (i.e. throw out rows that contain a maximum value greater than 0.5). It is possible to obtain the desired results utilizing partitions, there are just a few extra steps involved.

```
myComps <- t(as.matrix(compositions(20, 6))) / 20
myMax <- apply(myComps, 1, max)
temp <- myComps[-which(myMax > 0.5), ]
myFinalComps <- temp[do.call(order, as.data.frame(temp)), ]
all.equal(myPerms[do.call(order, as.data.frame(myPerms)), ], myFinalComps)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: don't you think you have not taken into consideration the fact that you just you need to have vectors that only have values in the positions indicated by 1?

Comment: @Onyambu To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what the OP is looking for. The OP states _"There can be no more than 6 "1"s anywhere in the vector. All other elements are 0"_ I get the feeling that the example they gave with three 1's was just an example and that they are looking for all possible combinations/permutations (not sure of that either) that will add to 1.

Comment: Well you might be right.. I guess I went with *So now for each one of those in temp I want to put in positions where the 1's are in*

Comment: @Onyambu, from the information given, the fact that the original vector has length 11 agrees with the `length(seq(0,0.5,0.05))` gives me more confidence that the OP is looking for the solution(s) I provided. Still though, not 100%. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Upvote for nice package and good demonstration. If you don't mind, I have one related question about your package. I tried the following code `myCombs <- permuteGeneral(seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05), 3, TRUE, constraintFun = "sum", comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = 1)`, which gives me a matrix with 162 rows. However, I cannot find some combination like `0.9, 0.05, 0.05`. Could you give some hints which steps I may do wrong?

Comment: This due to lack of precision. If you instead do `myCombs <- permuteGeneral(seq(5L, 95L, 5L), 3, TRUE, constraintFun = "sum", comparisonFun = "==", limitConstraints = 100L)/100`, you will get the correct answer. I will update my answer to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: @www, as of version `2.2.0`, the lack of precision has been fixed. If the class of the vector passed is `numeric` (i.e. double data type), the results are compared within machine precision. For example, if we are looking for results, say _comb_ which sum to a particular number _a_, instead of checking _comb = a_, we check to see if _abs(comb - a) < 0_ is satisfied. All of this is done with little to no additional overhead.

Comment: @JosephWood Thanks for your great work and share this information.

Comment: Correction... _abs(comb - a) < 0_ should be _abs(comb - a) < **epsilon**_

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible option. `dat5` is the final output.

```
# Create all possible combination from 1 to 19
dat1 <- expand.grid(L1 = 1:19, 
                    L2 = 1:19,
                    L3 = 1:19)

# Filter for the rows with sum = 20
dat2 <- dat1[rowSums(dat1) == 20L, ]

# Filter for the rows with no any numbers larger than 10
dat3 <- dat2[rowSums(dat2 > 10) == 0L, ]

# Convert the values by multiplied 0.05
dat4 <- dat3 * 0.05

# Convert the data frame to a list of vectors
dat4$ID <- 1:nrow(dat4)

dat5 <- lapply(split(dat4, f = dat4$ID), function(x){
  c(0, x$L1, 0, 0, x$L2, 0, 0, 0, 0, x$L3, 0)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe we need to only replace the 1's in the vector given. In that case, the zeros remain the same:

```
   s = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
   m = expand.grid(replicate(sum(s==1),seq(0,0.5,0.05),F))
    indx = replace(replace(s,s==1,1:ncol(m)),s==0,ncol(m)+1)

    dat = unname(cbind(m[rowSums(m)==1,],0)[indx])
    head(dat)

121 0 0.50 0 0 0.50 0 0 0 0 0.00 0
231 0 0.50 0 0 0.45 0 0 0 0 0.05 0
241 0 0.45 0 0 0.50 0 0 0 0 0.05 0
341 0 0.50 0 0 0.40 0 0 0 0 0.10 0
351 0 0.45 0 0 0.45 0 0 0 0 0.10 0
361 0 0.40 0 0 0.50 0 0 0 0 0.10 0
 tail(dat)

1271 0 0.25 0 0 0.25 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
1281 0 0.20 0 0 0.30 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
1291 0 0.15 0 0 0.35 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
1301 0 0.10 0 0 0.40 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
1311 0 0.05 0 0 0.45 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
1321 0 0.00 0 0 0.50 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
```